# Flash Pixel Bender: Number Crunching for Audio Processing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, effects, pixel-bender

I've seen some example of using a Pixel Bender for mixing two tracks together (per shader passes).

However, would it be technically possible to write a Pixel Bender kernel that could do this?

- Filter LP / HP / BP  (with Cutoff and
  Resonance parameters);
- Delays (with
  milliseconds timing and feedback
  parameters);
- Reverb (with Room size,
  Reverb length, Stereo Width
  parameters);
- Synthesizers (Square,
  Saw, Sine, Noise, custom waveshapes);

Comment: I use Ableton Live every once in a while, so it would be really cool to have some sort of Flash library / plugin that can do a lot of these common sound effects and generation.

Comment: Hmm, I think I may have just found what I was looking for!

**SiON** seems to do it all:

http://sites.google.com/site/sioncenter/specifications

It even sequences! But it would be interesting to know if it uses some kernel internally to process the audio.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Kevin Goldsmith's Pixel Bender Synth](http://www.kevingoldsmith.com/labs/PBSynth-v1/) too.